How to reference an encryption key and the latest version in bicep
If an encryption key is created in key vault using bicep, is there a way to reference the value of keyvault.properties.keyUriWithVersion without using the output functionality from the module that created the encryption key, if the name of the encryption key is known, is it possible to pull out keyUriWithVersion using the existing key word ?

yeah you can always use the existing key vault, just need to make sure the key is created before using the reference. Also could you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve ? Context could give us insights on pros and cons of idfferent approaches

You can either refer the keyVault properties, but also the child resources, such as Key. Below is my example code to show, remeber the deploymentScript here is just be used to demo the viability, you can use any actual resources which want to refer the Key property
param keyVaultName string = 'wbkeyvaultxxxx'

param keyName string = 'wbkeyxxxx'

param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-10-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource key 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: keyName
  parent: keyVault
}

// deploymentScript is just a print to demo it can refer the key existing property.
resource deploymentScript 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2023-08-01' = {
  name: 'testPrintTheString'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
  properties: {
    arguments: '-Uri ${key.properties.keyUriWithVersion}'
    scriptContent: 'param([string] $Uri) Write-Output $Uri'
    retentionInterval: 'PT1H'
    azPowerShellVersion: '11.5'
  }
}

